# Handling Tableau Date Filters in Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, api, tableau-api

I've been working in the [JavaScript API Tutorial](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/samples/en-us/js_api/tutorial.htm) that tableau provides.

The filter option works well on the Region filter, but for some reason stalls out on the "Year" filter.  Here's my code:

```
var viz;
var workbook;

// Initialize the javascript controls for Tableau
window.onload=function() {
    var vizDiv = document.getElementById('viz');
    var vizURL = 'http://public.tableau.com/views/WorldIndicators/GDPpercapita';
    var options = {
        width: '600px',
        height: '540px',
        hideToolbar: true,
        hideTabs: true,
        onFirstInteractive: function() {
        document.getElementById('sheetName').innerHTML=viz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet().getName();
        }
    }
    viz = new tableauSoftware.Viz(vizDiv,vizURL, options);
};

// Filter By Years
function addValuesToFilter() {
    activeSheet = viz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
    activeSheet.applyFilterAsync(
    "Year",
    ["2002", "2003"],
    tableau.FilterUpdateType.ADD);
}

// WORKING Filter Region
function addValuesToFilter() {
    activeSheet = viz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
    activeSheet.applyFilterAsync(
    "Region",
    ["Europe", "The Americas"],
    tableau.FilterUpdateType.ADD);
}
```

So I figure there must be some kid of 'getProperty' function to dump out the column names or something, but the API is pretty scant, and I'm not that great of a programmer.  I've taken a look into the .twb file's xml but it's mostly mumbo-jumbo and it's hard to make head or tail of what's going on in there.
Where am I going wrong here?  Is there a place I can get a list of filter names, or are date filters perhaps handled differently in Tableau?

Comment: will you post the working 'Region filter' code? maybe try numbers, instead of strings --> `[2002, 2003]` (lose the quotes)

Comment: Hi WhiteHat, did just that.  I tried numbers instead of strings, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you ever figured this out, but I got here looking for something else, so maybe this will help someone.

Here's how I list out the filter names.

```
activeSheet.getFiltersAsync().then(function(filters) {
    for (var x=0; x<filters.length; x++) {
        console.log(filters[x].getFieldName());
    }
});
```

If the filter is indeed named "Year", try a more descriptive name.  Could it be conflicting with another property in Tableau?  Date filters do get treated a bit differently in some circumstances (like if this filter is dependent on a another filter applied earlier).

Answer (score 1):

The list of filter names helped me.

Once I had the filter name (ex. "YEAR(Date (year))") the following worked.

```
function addYearToFilter() {
  activeSheet.applyFilterAsync(
      "YEAR(Date (year))",
      ["2008","2009"],
     tableau.FilterUpdateType.ADD);
}
```